# How to validate the UUID parameter before SQL request for a "GET item" request in API-Platform?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

Using:

- PostgreSQL 11 with `uuid_generate_v4` type
- Symfony 4.4.11
- Api Platform 2.5.6

I have an Entity with the following Id :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ContractRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Contract
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid", unique=true)
     */
    private $id;
[...]
```

I generate the following route with Api Platform :

```
App\Entity\Contract:
  itemOperations:
    get:
```

So I get a generated route like `/contracts/{id}`

Currently, if I do `/contracts/TEST`, it will try to do the SQL request with "TEST" in a where clause and so will fail as a `500`.

I would like to prevent this behaviour by asserting that the `{id}` parameter is a `UUID_v4` and return a `400` if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is DBMS specific, so you have to add your own logic.

The API-Platform component which retrieve an entity given an ID is the [ItemDataProviderInterface](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/#custom-item-data-provider).

1. First, I will declare a new exception `MalformedUuidException`.
2. Next, I will [convert this exception to a 400 error](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/errors/#converting-php-exceptions-to-http-errors).
3. Finally, I will create a new ItemDataProviderInterface implementation, wrapping the ORM one and adding some checks to the ID:

```php
class ContractDataProvider implements RestrictedDataProviderInterface, ItemDataProviderInterface
{
    /** @var ItemDataProviderInterface */
    private $realDataProvider;

    public function __construct(ItemDataProviderInterface $realDataProvider)
    {
        $this->realDataProvider = $realDataProvider;
    }

    public function getItem(string $resourceClass, $id, string $operationName = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $uuidPattern = '/^[a-f0-9]{8}-([a-f0-9]{4}-){3}[a-f0-9]{12}$/i';
        if (preg_match($uuidPattern, $id) === 1) {
            return $this->realDataProvider->getItem($resourceClass, ['id' => $id], $operationName, $context);
        } else {
            throw new MalformedUuidException("the given ID \"$id\" is not a valid UUID.");
        }
    }

    public function supports(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $resourceClass === Contract::class;
    }
}
```

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
    App\DataProvider\ContractDataProvider:
        arguments:
            $realDataProvider: '@api_platform.doctrine.orm.default.item_data_provider'
```

However, note that the `getItem()` method's contract does not specify the `MalformedUuidException` exception, so this implementation breaks the Liskov substitution principle.

Consider returning null instead and be satisfied with a 404 error.